# Redis on Azure VM vs Azure Redis Cache

Tags: redis, azure-redis-cache

We have checked both Redis installed in Azure VM and Azure Redis Cache both are working same I can't see a difference in the performance Have anyone used both in large scale application if so can anyone share the performance and durability of both ?

Have analysed the following

1. Monitoring
2. In-zone replication
3. Multi-zone replication
4. Auto fail-over
5. Data persistence
6. Backup
7. Pricing
8. SSL Authentication & Encryption

All the above Azure redis have the upper hand 
Still I want make sure which one is the best
Does using VM has any bottlenecks ?

Comment: It depends on your workload, the resources you use for your VM , the uptime expected. Also, how critical is redis component which decides if it should be HA or not.

Comment: It's worth mentioning using Azure Redis Cache comes with an [SLA](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/cache/v1_0/) which covers connectivity to the cache endpoints and support specifically for the Redis service (and not just the underlying VM) through Azure Support.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for Azure Redis Cache. Mainly because its fully managed. At the end of the day you do have nodes under the hood. But why should you care for maintaining a VM? Hotfixes? Patches, Seucirty Updates ..etc ..etc.

I would ask the question the other way around. Why should you use VMs at all?

MG